# I don't understand the CSS display property `display: block flow;`

Tags: css

Is `display: block flow;` the same as `display: block;`?
What does word flow mean in a two value syntax CSS property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#the-display-properties) it's the *outer* and *inner* display type

> the **inner** display type, which defines (if it is a non-replaced element) the kind of formatting context it generates, dictating how its descendant boxes are laid out. (The inner display of a replaced element is outside the scope of CSS.)
>
> the **outer** display type, which dictates how the principal box itself participates in flow layout.

And yes, `block` is the same as `block flow`

> If a `<display-outside>` value is specified but `<display-inside>` is omitted, the element’s inner display type defaults to **flow**.